# google map api is not working for a long time in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am just going for development of an android application on google map, but what error i am getting after some day of lunching the app in Playstore the google map is not working, only one page is coming and at right end of the page google icon is present.

Is there any way to fix this problem or we have to bye google api? Thank you.

Comment: can you share the error you're getting??

Comment: Hi, update your question with screenshots and code you suspect might be responsible.

Comment: might be the case you haven't used the correct api key while releasing your appliaction

Comment: @sumit This is my hunch as well.  It sounds like the map isn't loading at all, and I just saw this in my own work a few weeks ago (though sadly I forgot the actual cause).

Comment: Please share screen shot and error console with your question.

Comment: Your observations are consistent either with a problem with the API key or the app's inability to reach one of Google Map's servers.  You need to check for both of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by going to you api console 
from this  [link](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) then choose **credentials**
then choose your key and check the choose like next image [image]

Answer (score 0):

some api need billing accounts, Make sure that your protect is attached with billing account or not , if it is attached  than you should contact with google custom support center